# Search messages in the (remote) past

Tags: twitter, search

I would like to search Twitter messages containing a given search term, but in the relatively distant past (one week), potentially with the specification of a timeframe where the search is performed.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Topsy.com](http://topsy.com/advanced-search)

Answer (score 1):

Use the "until" option, on the search form at search.twitter.com or through the API: http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-Search-API-Method:-search

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Snap Bird](http://snapbird.org/) by Remy Sharp. It can search much further back in time than normal Twitter searches.

Answer (score 1):

Google search such as: "term1 term2 site:twitter.com".  On the results page click "More search tools" in the leftmost column, then click the desired date range (e.g. 'Past week') or click "Custom range..." to specify something more specific.

Answer (score 1):

[Searchtastic](http://www.searchtastic.com/) seems to search pretty far back, although I don't believe you can specify timeframe.  I've had good success with it.

Answer (score 1):

http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2010/04/replay-it-google-search-across-twitter.html

Not sure how it would work for you, but something to check out.

I also found this link comparing Twitter search sites.
http://mashable.com/2009/04/22/twitter-search-services/